# What is Log-Domain Filtering?

Tags: filter

Reading the report [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224277752_A_12_V_NPN-only_log-domain_integrator), they use 'Log-Domain Integration'.

It is said to be a type of 'Log-Domain' Filter, but googling it, there is just a bunch of reports/articles on it.

Can anyone explain what Log-Domain filtering is and why we might use it over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very low supply voltages (1V or even lower) we can use the principle of analog signal processing in the "log domain". Using this principle, the exponential current-voltage characteristic of bipolar transistors (for very small currents) or of MOSFETs (sub-threshold region) is exploited.

The principle is based on a kind of "companding": The input signal is a current, which produces a "compressed" voltage in the log-domain - and after signal processing in this domain (amplification, intergation, filtering) the voltage signal is expanded and transferred back again into a current using the exponential characteristic of a transistor (inverse operation if compared with the input expansion).

In all cases, log-domain signal processing is realized in form of integrated circuits only. And as the main advantage very low supply voltages are allowed.

**Literature:**

Here is a good introductory text:

http://bioelectronics.tudelft.nl/~wout/documents/iscas20022.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to the first google result 'what is log domain filtering?':

[Synthesis of Log-Domain Filters from First-Order Building Blocks](http://isn.ucsd.edu/pubs/aicsp00_log.pdf)

First part of 1. Introduction:

Definition:

```
Log-domain filters comprise a subclass of circuits
having externally linear transfer functions but
internally nonlinear components [1,2]. As the name
implies, log-domain filters are specifically those
circuits whose internal state is a logarithmic function
of the input and output. The circuit design exploits this
particular nonlinearity directly rather than attempting
linearization around an operating point. The result is
that log-domain filters have large-signal linearity: the
transfer function describes the overall behavior of the
system.
```

Usage:

```
The equations governing the internal nonlinearity
of the system are generally tractable, leading
to complete solutions which do not require separate
DC and transient analyses.
```

Comment: If you use quote instead of code/block markup one can easily read that on a mobile device too